# MQRC 2035 when using qload supportpac

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

We recently installed qload supporpac to load/unload the messages from the queue to/from queue(or)file.

We are able to copy the messages from the queue to a file. But when we are loading the messages from the file to the queue, it is throwing 2035 error.

```
qload -fmyfile -oQL.MQ.TEST -m QA01
QLOAD Program by Paul Clarke [ V1.9 Build:Jun 26 2012 ]
MQOPEN on object 'QL.MQ.TEST' returned 2035 Not authorized..
```

We are facing same error when we are trying to move the messages from one queue to another queue using qload.

```
qload -iQL.INPUT -oQL.MQ.TEST -m QA01
QLOAD Program by Paul Clarke [ V1.9 Build:Jun 26 2012 ]
MQOPEN on object 'QL.MQ.TEST' returned 2035 Not authorized..
```

Where as we are able to copy the messages from one queue to another using q utility.We have set the proper authorizations both on the queues and QMGR for the group id.

Since it is throwing error at MQOPEN, I can consider that, it is able to connect to QMGR but failing to open the queue. If so, why qload is able to copy the messages from the queue to a file?

Shouldn't it throw 2035 error while opening the queue to copy messages on to a file?

Comment: What are the actual permissions set on the queue QL.MQ.TEST? It seems that you don't have put permissions on QL.MQ.TEST, only get.

Comment: Can you show us the content of AMQERR0x.log at the time of running the test? It should give a more specific reason for the 2035.

Comment: Using dspmqaut or dmpmqaut to show your authorities for these objects may be helpful in troubleshooting.